# Output meta into arrays

Tags: loop, get-posts, array, post-meta, php

I'm creating a loop which wouldn't output anything visible to the user, but needed to create a calculation later on.

I have:

```
// posts for the week mon-fri
$week_array = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => array('publish'),
    'date_query'       => array(
        'before'    => 'next Saturday',
        'after'     => 'last Monday',
    )
);

$week_count = get_posts( $week_array );

$array01 = array();
$array02 = array();

echo '<h1>' . count( $week_count ) . ' posts this week</h1>';
foreach( $week_count as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $a = rand(5,15);

    $meta_array01 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_login',  true );
    $meta_array02 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta_logout', true );


     $array01[$post->ID] = $meta_array01;
     $array02[$post->ID] = $meta_array02;

}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

My main intention would have been to have something like this outputted:

```
array(
    [167] => array(
                'meta_login'  => 2016-10-25 18:34:55
                'meta_logout' => 2016-10-25 19:15:12
             ),

    [168] => array(
                'meta_login'  => ...
                'meta_logout' => ...
             )
    ... // and so on for each matching post
);
```

But I couldn't figure that out, so I thought to merge the two arrays above into one, but when I use `array_merge_recursive()` I get an array from 0 to the last number of posts, but lose their order.

Effectively, my aim is to calculate the time between the two meta fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'fields' => 'ids'` to skip setting up the post and just create the array you want in the `foreach`.

```
$week_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'date_query'     => array(
        'before' => 'next Saturday',
        'after'  => 'last Monday',
    ),
);

$week_array = get_posts( $week_args );
$week_count = count( $week_array );

printf( '<h1>%s posts this week</h1>', $week_count );

$dates = array();
foreach ( $week_array as $post_id ) {

    $login  = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_login', true );
    $logout = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_logout', true );

    $dates[ $post_id ] = array(
        "meta_login"  => $login ? $login : 0,
        "meta_logout" => $logout ? $logout : 0,
        "dif"         => abs(strtotime($logout) - strtotime($login)),
    );
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $dates );
```

Comment: Works perfect, and solves quite a few later things I wanted to do!

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the get_post_meta WP function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ reveals that using it with the parameter $single set to (bool) 'true' the function returns the meta_value of the requested meta_key. If the parameter $single is set to (bool) 'false' then it returns an array of the meta_value or values (in case there are multiple values matching the query) for the requested meta_key.

So to get your desired output you could go at it like this:

```
foreach( $week_count as $post ) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    $a = rand(5,15);

     $meta_array[$post->ID] = array( 'meta_login' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_login',  true), 
                                     'meta_logout' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_logout', true)
                                    );
}
```